# tensorflow-data-validation cannot be pip installed

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-data-validation

Since I'm moving away from pandas DataFrames to TensorFlow datasets, I'd like to use [`tensorflow-data-validation`](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation) instead of the more traditional [`pandas-profiling`](https://github.com/pandas-profiling) when it comes to data exploration and validation.

However, `pip install tensorflow-data-validation` gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-data-validation (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-data-validation
```

What could be the problem? [This old GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/issues/7) explains how this could be due to the Python version, but Apache Beam (on which `tensorflow-data-validation` presumably relies) is now fully compatible with Python 3, so it must be something else.

My environment is as follows:

- Python 3.9.2
- TensorFlow 2.6.0
- Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- pip 21.3

Comment: Any luck with this one? I still can't install tensorflow-data-validation because Google Vertex AI is stuck on pyarrow 6.0.1 and it refuses to install the correct versions. I've been trying for the past 5+ hours and I still can't get it to work. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when using Python 3.9. After downgrading to Python 3.8, `pip install tensorflow-data-validation` ran successfully.

Regarding your comment about Apache Beam, it looks like the Python SDK currently supports [Python 3.8](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8494) (and earlier) but not yet [Python 3.9](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12000).

My environment:

- Python 3.8.10
- TensorFlow 2.8.0
- macOS Monterey (12.0.1)
- pip 21.1.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-data-validation[all]
```

Comment: I get `no matches found: tensorflow-data-validation[all]` since the package couldn't get installed in the first place.

Comment: check if you have internet acces from the terminal you are using

Comment: I do. I even checked that the computer is powered on.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a version compatibility issue with tensorflow==2.6.0.
Try

```
pip install tensorflow-data-validation==1.3.0
```

Comment: That produced the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the tensorflow_data_validation library successfully, via the below command in my Google Colab file.

```
!pip install -U tensorflow \
            tensorflow-data-validation \
            apache-beam[gcp]
```